# How to get proper collection in magento grid?

Tags: mysql, magento, grid

I have a custom grid tab in magento category with separate table to store data.

**This is table with data:**

[image: tcategoryacl table]

When I filter by 'Yes' under first column. It does return associated rows with ID (284 & 285) but when I select 'No', it returns IDs (281-283), it's supposed to return 283 only which is the only stream not configured already.

And when I select ANY, it returns all associated and not associated with duplicate streams to select.

What I need is show each streams once only and work with first column filter.

[image: wrong]

I think I have incorrect joins with another table which holds all the streams (groups).

**This is another table**
[image: streams]

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    if ($this->getCategory()->getId()) {
        $this->setDefaultFilter(array('selected_tcategoryacl'=>1));
    }
    /* @var $collection Technooze_Tcategoryacl_Model_Mysql4_Tcategoryacl_Collection */
    $collection = Mage::getModel('tcategoryacl/tcategoryacl')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->joinRight('school_group', 'school_group_id=group_id');
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('school_group_status', 1);
    //$collection->getSelect()->group('school_group.school_group_id');

    $collection = $this->insertFakeIdsToCollection($collection);
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
{
    $tcategoryaclIds = $this->_getSelectedTcategoryacl();
    switch($column->getId()){
        case 'selected_tcategoryacl':
            if (empty($tcategoryaclIds)) {
                $tcategoryaclIds = 0;
            }
            //$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('category_id', $this->getCategory()->getId());
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->removeRightJoin();
                $this->getCollection()->clear()->addFieldToFilter('tcategoryacl_id', array('in'=>$tcategoryaclIds));
            } elseif(!empty($tcategoryaclIds)) {
                $this->getCollection()->clear();
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('tcategoryacl_id', array('nin'=>$tcategoryaclIds));
                //$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('school_group.school_group_id', array('nin'=>$this->_getSelectedSchoolGroupIds()));
                $this->setCollection($this->insertFakeIdsToCollection($this->getCollection()));
            }
            break;
        /*case 'allow_from':
        case 'allow_to':
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($column->getId(), array('like'=>$column->getFilter()->getValue()));
            break;*/
        default: parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }

    return $this;
}

private function removeRightJoin(){
    $this->getCollection()->clear()->getSelect()->reset('RIGHT JOIN');
}

protected function insertFakeIdsToCollection($collection)
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach($collection as $v){
        // lets have fake ids for empty tcategoryacl_id, so checkbox can be selected
        if(!$v->getData('tcategoryacl_id')){
            $v->setData('tcategoryacl_id', '0' . $this->getCategory()->getId() . $i++);
            $v->setId($v->getData('tcategoryacl_id'));
        }

        // lets auto select different groups in each row
        if(!$v->getData('group_id')){
            $v->setData('group_id', $v->getData('school_group_id'));
        }
    }
    return $collection;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getSelectedSchoolGroupIds()
{
    $selected_tcategoryacl = array();
    $category = $this->getCategory();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('tcategoryacl/tcategoryacl')->getCollection();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('category_id', $category->getId());

    foreach($collection as $v)
    {
        $selected_tcategoryacl[] = $v->getGroupId();
    }
    return $selected_tcategoryacl;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getSelectedTcategoryacl()
{
    $selected_tcategoryacl = array();
    $category = $this->getCategory();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('tcategoryacl/tcategoryacl')->getCollection();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('category_id', $category->getId());

    foreach($collection as $v)
    {
        $selected_tcategoryacl[] = $v->getTcategoryaclId();
    }
    return $selected_tcategoryacl;
}
```

## Update

*added code on repo - https://github.com/dbashyal/Tcategory_ACL/blob/master/app/code/community/Technooze/Tcategoryacl/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Category/Tab/Tcategoryacl.php*

Comment: which table are you using to store the selected Group Permissions?

Comment: @MTM first one above '*tcategoryacl*'